# F# sum of a list of lists

Tags: f#

I created my own datatype And I'm trying to create the sum of all the numbers in that datatype which is a list of lists.  I don't want to use any F# libraries

My datatype

```
type elist = A | L of int * elist
```

I'm a beginner in F# and trying to grasp my head on it.  I want to do this recursively.  My thinking going into it is to traverse to the end of the list and start an sum and go back to the front and add each one.

example:

```
let l = L(4, L(3, L(6, L(3, A))))
```

that should return

```
val it : int 16
```

Here's my code and I know it is wrong:

```
let rec sum l = 
   let a = 0
   match l with
   | A -> 0
   | L(head,A) -> head 
   | L(head,tail) -> sum tail + a
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/39461659/126014 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/39462259/126014 Almost certainly homework.

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there. All you need is to lose the `a`:

```
let rec sum l = 
   match l with
   | A -> 0
   | L(head,A) -> head 
   | L(head,tail) -> head + sum tail
```

Then evaluating `sum l` when `l = L(4, L(3, L(6, L(3, A))))` gives

```
val it : int = 16
```

as required.

Comment: Thank You @RobLyndon.  If I wanted to find the nth element of the list l, how would my code differ?

Comment: `let rec element l n = match (l, n) with | (A, _) -> failwith "Out of range" | (L(head, A), k) when k > 0 -> failwith "Out of range" | (L(head, A), 0) -> head | (L(head, tail), 0) -> head | (L(head, tail), k) when k > 0 -> element tail (k - 1)`